# vich uploader and easy admin images not showing

Tags: symfony, image-uploading, vichuploaderbundle, symfony2-easyadmin

I'm following the tutorial from (https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/integration/vichuploaderbundle.html)

I was able to upload the image, but it´s not appearing in the list view of easy-admin.

It goes like this:

```
#easy_admin.yaml
easy_admin:
  entities:
    Manchete:
      class:  App\Entity\Manchete
      form:
        fields:
          - titulo
          - descricao
          - link
          - {  property: 'arquivoDaImagem', type: 'vich_image', base_path: '%app.path.manchete_images%',
               help: 'selecione uma imagem para a manchete',
                , label: 'Imagem da manchete', template: 'vich_uploader_image.html.twig' }



      # ...
      list:
        fields:
        - titulo
        - descricao
        - link
        - {  property: 'imagem', template: 'vich_uploader_image.html.twig' }
      # ...
      show:
        fields:
        - titulo
        - descricao
        - link
        - {  property: 'imagem', template: 'vich_uploader_image.html.twig' }
```

Below are the path to upload the file:

```
#vich_uploader.yalm
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm

    mappings:
        manchete_images:
            uri_prefix: '%app.path.manchete_images%' 
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/%app.path.manchete_images%'
```

---

```
#services.yaml
parameters:
    locale: 'en'
    app.path.manchete_images: /uploads/images/manchetes
```

---

The file and the images are being uploaded to the folder:

[image]

---

but aren't being displayed inside easy admin view

[image]

It´s my first time using Symfony all these related techniques, so I´m a little lost here.

Comment: What is the url for those images that appear broken?

Comment: does this make sense?
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/?entity=Manchete&action=list&menuIndex=0&submenuIndex=-1&sortField=id&sortDirection=DESC&page=1#

I mean, is this the answer you @dbrumann wanted?

Comment: I mean when you click right click on the broken image, what url does it show, i.e. where does the browser look for the image. Does it match the path? If the parameter `app.path.manchete_images: /uploads/images/manchetes` results in the url `127.0.0.1/uploads/images/manchetes` then that could be the problem, as the answer by Ahmed implies, i.e. the uri_prefix should not contain the public folder.

Comment: hey @dbrumann, I followed Ahmed and worked,... just by putting the public folder in the path of the upload_destination... now, my next challenge is get the image in the controller and show in the twig template... =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put your images under **public** folder, try this mapping configuration:

```
   manchete_images:
            uri_prefix:         '%app.path.manchete_images%'
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/%app.path.manchete_images%'
```

Comment: hey @AhmedEBENHASSINE, thanks a lot... yes, now it´s working... but 

uri_prefix : must have single-quotes like this -> '%app.path.manchete_images%'

thanks a lot...

Comment: Hey @AdrielWerlich yes I just edited we need to add the quotes, as the doc mention here https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-1-yaml-deprecations
Could do you please accept my anwser ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thanks to @Ahmed suggestion, it´s showing now...
thought the uri_prefix should contain single quote marks, otherwise exception occurs...

like this:

```
manchete_images:
            uri_prefix:  '%app.path.manchete_images%'   
            upload_destination:  '%kernel.project_dir%/public/%app.path.manchete_images%'
```

[image]

thanks again...